# unity updating variable from different thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, unity-game-engine, mono

I am starting to learn some unity and I have a quick question in regards to multithreading.

I have a class which contains an instance of a datamodel class. The primary function of the class is the fetch a remote resource asynchronously and update the datamodel class. Then in the update function the datamodel class is read out and written to some text in a gameobject.

Anyway I am worrying that it could cause some issues related to multithreading since my async updating of the class could run at the same time as the update function causing a race condition. Do I have to wrap access to the class in a mutex?

```
class Data {
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Network : MonoBehaviour {
    private Data d;

    public void Start() {
        // setting up handler to async fetch data and call provided callback
        Networking.GetData(s => ParsePayload(s));
    }

    private void ParsePayload(string payload) {
        d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(payload);
    }

    public void Update() {
        var label = GameObject.Find("textObject").GetComponent<Text>();
        label.Text = d.Name;
    }
}
```

So am I right in this or does unity handle this by itself?

thx for any advice!

Comment: Without posting your code, any answer you get will likely not be useful to you. at-least, try to show what you are doing

Comment: @Programmer updated my question...

Comment: Where are you updating the class and where is the Thread code. This is missing. If you have both of these, somebody here can help you answer this.

Comment: @programmer it isn't missing.... ParsePayload()

Comment: You only answered part the missing question. `ParsePayload` is passed into another `Thread` for callback and that `Thread` will call it when result is available. Now, where is the Thread code that calls `ParsePayload`?  Does it access `Data d` anywhere?

Comment: @Programmer `Data d` isn't accessed anywhere outside of the class. But ParsePayload still runs in a different thread.

Comment: @JohnSmith, there is almost *no reason* to ever use separate threads in Unity.  You should almost certainly forget about this.  (Regarding grabbing something from the www, it's totally trivial, just google.)

Comment: @JoeBlow Really? all solution either use coroutines which is basically multithreading or try to force it into a generator which is a bad fit, since you still will have blocking calls.

Comment: just use www, it goes to another thread for you.  all you're doing is getting something from the web - it's nothing. one line of code

Comment: @JohnSmith There is a new solution for this. Ignore the one I left even though it works. Look at the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So am I right in this or does unity handle this by itself?

You are right in this. It could cause some problems and Unity does **not** handle this by itself. You are responsible to making sure that only one Thread can access `d` variable at a time. There are several ways of this but using the `lock` keyword can accompilsh this.

Since `d` is updated in the `ParsePayload` function and accessed in the `Update` function, you have to use the `lock` keyword in both functions.

Another unrelated problem is the `GameObject.Find("textObject")`. This should be done in the `Start()` function and saved to a variable. Don't do that in the Update function each frame.

```
class Network : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Data d;
    Text label;

    private System.Object threadLocker = new System.Object();

    public void Start()
    {
        label = GameObject.Find("textObject").GetComponent<Text>();

        // setting up handler to async fetch data and call provided callback
        Networking.GetData(s => ParsePayload(s));
    }

    private void ParsePayload(string payload)
    {
        lock (threadLocker)
        {
            d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(payload);
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        lock (threadLocker)
        {
            label.text = d.Name;
        }
    }
}
```